# Xamarin Forms iOS renderer Dimensions

Tags: xamarin.forms

I’m trying to create a “generic” renderer for iOS and I have trouble figuring out the dimensions of the renderer.

The class of the renderer in the PCL is very simple and the only “peculiar” is that inherits from a `View` since I want to have it as a generic renderer

```
public class ExampleView : View { }
```

In the XAML, it is also very typical

```
<renderers:ExampleView />
```

The definition of the renderer in the iOS project is the following

```
public class ExampleRenderer : ViewRenderer<ExampleView, UIView>
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<ExampleView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control == null)
        {
            SetNativeControl(new UIView(new CGRect(0, 0, 0, 300)));
        }
    }
}
```

The interesting part here is that the class inherits from `ViewRenderer<ExampleView, UIView>`

It seems that although I specify that the width of the render to be 0, the actual renderer takes the entire width of the page.

In fact whatever value I put as width, will be disregarded, and the renderer will occupy the entire page.

This is not bad, it is unintentional and this is what bother me. (or Am I doing something wrong?)

So the question here is how can find in my custom render, the width that occupies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not the renderer, but the native control that is taking up the space. The renderer is doing it's job i.e. keep the native control in sync with forms control - which includes l[ayout parse requests](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS/ViewRenderer.cs#L57).

To control the size constraints I would recommend using the properties `WidthRequest` or `HeightRequest` on forms `Element` to do that. It will automatically trickle down to the native `Control`.`Frame` through the renderer.

**EDIT-1**

If you want to update your native controls (or subviews) based on current bounds you can use `OnElementPropertyChanged` to track the changes. There can many reasons that can cause a size-update - like device-orientation change, parent layout, first layout pass etc.

```
public class ExampleRenderer : ViewRenderer<ExampleView, UIView>
{
    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

        if (e.PropertyName == VisualElement.WidthProperty.PropertyName ||
            e.PropertyName == VisualElement.HeightProperty.PropertyName)
        {
            if(Element != null && Element.Bounds.Height > 0 && Element.Bounds.Width > 0)
            {
                //update size on native control's subviews
                // or use SetNeedsDisplay() to re-draw
                //Note: force update to Control's size is not recommended (as it is recommended it be same as forms element)
                //Instead add a subview that you can update for size here
            }   
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried the `WidthRequest` and the `HeightRequest` before asking the question and they didn't make any difference. Actually, the numbers that I assigned to these properties don't appear anywhere in the custom renderer. In the code that I posted the native control doesn't have any size yet! So how can I ask from the control to occupy half of the screen size since I don't know the size of the screen and I don;t know how to get it? The `e.NewElement.Bounds` give width and height equal to -1.

Comment: WidthRequest and HeighRequest can be ignored in some parent layouts. The native control is expected to have a size only after layout pass has happened for forms-element. To be able to track element bounds - you will need to use `OnElementPropertyChanged` (similar to `OnSizeAllocated`)

Comment: Yes, it’s working. It seems that just a `SetNativeControl(new UIView());` will do. As you said, I can specify the HeightRequest in XAML. The sequence of events is important. First is the `OnElementChanged`, then multiple passes from the `OnElementPropertyChanged` and then in the `if` statement, the `SetNeedsDisplay();` will trigger the `Draw(CGRect rect)` where I have the final `rect` with proper values. I was doing the drawing before which is a mistake. Thanks a lot.